# How do I partially fold a Vec in place?

Tags: coding-style, rust

I would like to walk through a Vec and combine some elements of it. How do I do that in **idiomatic** Rust?

#### Example:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
enum Thing { A, B, AandB }
fn combine(v: Vec<Thing>) -> Vec<Thing> {
    // idiomatic code here
}

fn main() {
     let v = vec![Thing::A, Thing::B];
     assert_eq!(vec![Thing::AandB], combine(v));
}
```

#### How I would do it:

Traverse the Vec with Iterator::scan and replace all occurrences of Thing::B with Thing::AandB if Thing::A was the element before. Then I would traverse it again and remove all Thing::As before Thing::AandB.

This seems super complicated and inelegant.

Comment: You haven't clearly defined what's going on; what happens to `B`s that aren't preceeded by `A`s?  What about `AandB`s that are already there?  Also, do you want the transformation to happen *within* the `Vec`, or is allocating a new one OK?

Comment: sorry! I just want to combine A followed by B. AandBs should be ignored if already present. the transformation should work on the vector directly!

Comment: done! thank you for your huge time investment into my problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I merged swizard's answer and Shepmaster's answer and ended up with an in-place solution that runs through the vector recursively, has only the vector as a mutable and never moves anything twice. No guarantees on runtime or idiomaticity ;)

```
use Thing::*;
use std::cmp::min;

#[derive(Copy,Clone,PartialEq,Debug)]
enum Thing { A, B, AandB}

fn combine(mut v: Vec<Thing>) -> Vec<Thing> {
    fn inner(res: &mut Vec<Thing>, i: usize, backshift: usize) {
        match &res[i..min(i+2, res.len())] {
            [A, B] => {
                res[i - backshift] = AandB;
                inner(res, i + 2, backshift + 1);
            },
            [a, ..] => {
                res[i - backshift] = a;
                inner(res, i + 1, backshift);
            },
            [] => res.truncate(i - backshift),
        }
    };

    inner(&mut v, 0, 0);
    v
}

fn main() {
     let v = vec![A, A, B, AandB, B, A, B, A, B];
     assert_eq!(vec![A, AandB, AandB, B, AandB, AandB], combine(v));
     let v = vec![A, A, B, AandB, B, A, B, A, A];
     assert_eq!(vec![A, AandB, AandB, B, AandB, A, A], combine(v));
}
```

Comment: impressive! this meets the requirements by 100%! thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this counts as idiomatic, but the [itertools](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) library has the `batching()` function for all iterators. Combined with `peek()` from the standard library, you get your result in one iteration instead of two.

```
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Itertools;
use Thing::*;

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
enum Thing { A, B, AandB }
fn combine(v: Vec<Thing>) -> Vec<Thing> {
    v.into_iter().peekable().batching(|mut it| {
        match it.next() {
            Some(A) => {
                if Some(&B) == it.peek() {
                    it.next();
                    Some(AandB)
                } else {
                    Some(A)
                }
            }
            x => x,
        }
    }).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![A, B, A, A, A, B, B, A];
    assert_eq!(
        vec![AandB, A, A, AandB, B, A],
        combine(v)
    );
}
```

obviously `collect()` [will allocate a new buffer](http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/collections/vec.rs.html#1396-1406).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses recursion and pattern-matching. I'm pretty sure the recursion is tail-recursion, and so could be turned into iteration.

```
use Thing::*;

#[derive(Copy,Clone,PartialEq,Debug)]
enum Thing { A, B, AandB }

fn combine(v: Vec<Thing>) -> Vec<Thing> {
    fn inner(mut res: Vec<Thing>, s: &[Thing]) -> Vec<Thing> {
        match s {
            [A, B, tail..] => {
                res.push(AandB);
                inner(res, tail)
            },
            [a, tail..] => {
                res.push(a);
                inner(res, tail)
            },
            [] => res,
        }
    };

    inner(Vec::new(), &v)
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![A, A, B, AandB, B, A];
    assert_eq!(vec![A, AandB, AandB, B, A], combine(v));

    let v = vec![A, A, B, AandB, B, A, B, A, B];
    assert_eq!(vec![A, AandB, AandB, B, AandB, AandB], combine(v));

    let v = vec![A, A, B, AandB, B, A, B, A, A];
    assert_eq!(vec![A, AandB, AandB, B, AandB, A, A], combine(v));
}
```

Comment: this is very beautiful rust code, thank you! I really like how elegant the language is sometimes!

Comment: you can get rid of the mutable variable r by making inner return a Vec<Thing> and passing res by mutable value. Playpen: http://is.gd/4cMULe

Comment: @ker turns out that pair code-golfing is the best kind of code-golfing! ^_^ Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is no easy way to do that with iterators, but nobody lays embargo on plain old c-style:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Copy)]
enum Thing { A, B, AandB }
fn combine(mut v: Vec<Thing>) -> Vec<Thing> {
    let mut prev: Option<Thing> = None;
    let mut end = 0;
    for i in 0 .. v.len() {
        let el = v[i];
        match (el, prev) {
            (Thing::B, Some(Thing::A)) => {
                end = end - 1;
                v[end] = Thing::AandB
            },
            _ => 
                v[end] = el
        };
        prev = Some(el);
        end = end + 1;
    }

    v.truncate(end);
    v
}

fn main() {
     let v = vec![Thing::A, Thing::A, Thing::B, Thing::AandB, Thing::B, Thing::A];
     assert_eq!(vec![Thing::A, Thing::AandB, Thing::AandB, Thing::B, Thing::A], combine(v));
}
```

Here is one pass with direct transformations.

Comment: thank you very much! this will surely work and be fast, but it's not idiomatic rust in any way :p thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is an idiomatic version then without explicit for-loops and recursion :)

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Copy)]
enum Thing { A, B, AandB }
fn combine(mut v: Vec<Thing>) -> Vec<Thing> {
    let (_, total) = (0 .. v.len()).fold((None, 0), |&mut: (prev, end), i| {
        let el = v[i];
        let (next, item) = match (el, prev) {
            (Thing::B, Some(Thing::A)) => (end, Thing::AandB),
            _ => (end + 1, el),
        };
        v[next - 1] = item;
        (Some(el), next)
    });

    v.truncate(total);
    v
}

fn main() {
     let v = vec![Thing::A, Thing::A, Thing::B, Thing::AandB, Thing::B, Thing::A];
     assert_eq!(vec![Thing::A, Thing::AandB, Thing::AandB, Thing::B, Thing::A], combine(v));
}
```